# Light not rendering

Tags: rendering, light

almost a complete beginner here. I'm trying to render my object with a lightsource but the light does not render.

I used a Point Light, placed it right on top and turned the Energy and Falloff all the way up but it still doesnt illuminate my object.

If i do a new project and add lights they work as supposed to.

Any ideas what i might have messed up during the process?

Thx in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are in *material shading* in *blender render* (the option to the right of the file bar). Change to cycles render and then try switching to any other option in viewport shading.